# Ampersands in a URL are converted to "amp;" when converting to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, url-encoding

I'm using a PHP function called [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to convert some URL-encoded data (like "name=blah&number=123") to a PHP array. It does work correctly, but it puts an "amp;" at the beginning of each key in the resulting associative array, except the first key. For example:

```
response=Fail&responsecode=1&description=DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION
```

is converted to the following array:

```
Array ( [ \"1.0\" 
encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
response=Fail 
[amp;responsecode] => 1 
[amp;description] => DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION)
```

using the following code:

```
parse_str($response, $response_array);
print_r($response_array);
```

I'm not sure why it's adding those "amp;"s. What's the problem here?

Comment: did you decode the url first?

Comment: @Ahmad I'm not sure. I did try just printing the URL, and the ampersands were just regular ampersands (I pasted them in this question).

Comment: Why dont you use parse_url() instead? `parse_url($string, $output)`

Comment: That just returned "Array ( [path] => )". I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: Make sure you're examining the output either in the web source view or in a console - `&amp;` and `&` are generally indistinguishable in a web browser.

Comment: @SamDufel Yes, but even regular ampersands shouldn't be there. The idea is I'd like to access the array with eg `$response_array["description"];`.

Comment: Just tested your code with the string given, it works just fine,  You are probably getting an encoded url string try this `urldecode($response)`

Comment: @Tigger Because this is returned from a cURL request.

Comment: @Hassan - Don't think about what should be there, look at what actually is there.  If the original string contains `&amp;`, the ampersand would become the separator and you'd be left with `amp;` at the beginning of each array value.

Comment: @Ahmad I tried that, but it still gave me those "amp;"s.

Comment: @SamDufel Actually, echoing the original string shows regular ampersands. Those are supposed to be the separators, but why are they added to the beginning of each key in the array?

Comment: Did you view it in a web browser, or did you look at the page source / console output?

Comment: @SamDufel I viewed it in a browser window. How can I check in a console output?

Comment: @Hassan what do you see when you do `var_dump($response)`

Comment: @Ahmad I get: `string(614) " response=Fail&responsecode=1&description=DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION"`. Of course there's more, but those are the first few fields I used as an example.

Comment: @Hassan do `parse_str(html_entity_decode($response) )` instead of `parse_str($response) `

Comment: @Ahmad Wow that worked! I really appreciate your help. I will accept your answer if you submit one.

Comment: @Hassan Glad it worked, make sure you vote up my suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [cannot reproduce it](http://3v4l.org/mYJl7):

```
<?php

$response = 'response=Fail&responsecode=1&description=DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION';
parse_str($response, $response_array);
print_r($response_array);
```

```
Array
(
    [response] => Fail
    [responsecode] => 1
    [description] => DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION
)
```

However, you provide a useful hint in one of your comments:

```
string(614) " response=Fail&responsecode=1&description=DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION"
```

That's obviously not a 614 byte string. Your data is not `response=Fail&responsecode=1&description=DUPLICATE_TRANSACTION`.

That, and the fact that you're getting this:

```
[ \"1.0\" 
encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
```

... suggests that you actually have an XML or HTML document, but you are letting the browser render it as HTML, thus the tags are  hidden. Please use your browser's "View Source" feature (typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) to see the real input.